# Prove that if $a \in (\mathbb{Z/nZ})^\times$, then $-a \in (\mathbb{Z/nZ})^\times$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $a \in (\mathbb{Z/nZ})^\times$ then $ax+ny = 1$ for some $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$

$$-a = n - a$$

Then

$$ny = 1 - ax = 1 + (-a)x$$

Putting value of -a

$$ny = 1 + (n-a)x \qquad \implies (a-n)x + ny = 1 \qquad \implies ax + n(y-x) = 1$$

Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly write $ax+ny=1 \implies (-a)(-x)+ny =1$.